# Can't expose inner control's property from my own control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a view which I would like to reuse, it looks as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Klein.DocumentSample.View.UserControls.CollectionView"
    ...
    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup x:Name="tasksPageGroup" Caption="Customer Tasks">
        <dxr:RibbonPageGroup.Items>
            <dxb:BarButtonItem Content="New" Command="{Binding NewCommand}"  LargeGlyph="{dx:DXImage Image=New_32x32.png}" Glyph="{dx:DXImage Image=New_16x16.png}"/>
            <dxb:BarButtonItem Content="Edit" Command="{Binding EditCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedEntity}" LargeGlyph="{dx:DXImage Image=Edit_32x32.png}" Glyph="{dx:DXImage Image=Edit_16x16.png}"/>
            <dxb:BarButtonItem Content="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedEntity}" LargeGlyph="{dx:DXImage Image=Delete_32x32.png}" Glyph="{dx:DXImage Image=Delete_16x16.png}"/>
            <dxb:BarButtonItem Content="Refresh" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"  LargeGlyph="{dx:DXImage Image=Refresh_32x32.png}" Glyph="{dx:DXImage Image=Refresh_16x16.png}"/>
        </dxr:RibbonPageGroup.Items>
    </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
    ...
</UserControl>
```

All usages of this control will have the four buttons (New, Edit, Delete and Refresh). But some usages, will have more buttons, besides these. Therefore I would like to make `CollectionView` expose `tasksPageGroup.Items`, so I can add more buttons, like this:

```
<Window
    <Grid>
        <userControls:CollectionView>
            <userControls:CollectionView.TasksPageGroup>
                <userControls:CollectionView.TasksPageGroup.Items>
                    <!-- This is the 5th button -->
                    <dxb:BarButtonItem Content="Reset" Command="{Binding ResetCommand}"  LargeGlyph="{dx:DXImage Image=Reset_32x32.png}" Glyph="{dx:DXImage Image=Reset_16x16.png}"/>
                </userControls:CollectionView.TasksPageGroup.Items>
        </userControls:CollectionView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is my code behind:

```
public partial class CollectionView : UserControl
{
    public RibbonPageGroup TasksPageGroup
    {
        get { return tasksPageGroup; }
    }

    public CollectionView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

How can this be achieved?

Desired Usage:

```
<Grid>
    <dxb:BarManager>
        <dxb:BarManager.Items>
            <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="testeButtonItem" Content="New" Command="{Binding TesteCommand}"  LargeGlyph="{dx:DXImage Image=New_32x32.png}" Glyph="{dx:DXImage Image=New_16x16.png}"/>
        </dxb:BarManager.Items>
    </dxb:BarManager>
    <userControls:CollectionView>
        <userControls:CollectionView.Tasks>
            <dxb:BarItemLink BarItemName="testeButtonItem" />
        </userControls:CollectionView.Tasks>
    </userControls:CollectionView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typically won't expose inner workings of yourself like that. In WPF, to expose a property to the outside world, you put a `DependencyProperty` out there:

```
public IList<BarButtonItem> Tasks
    {
        get { return (IList<BarButtonItem >)GetValue(TasksProperty);                }
        set { SetValue(TasksProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Colors.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TasksProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Tasks", typeof(IList<BarButtonItem>), typeof(CollectionView), new PropertyMetadata(new List<BarButtonItem>()));
```

Now, be **careful** here. Initializing the property metadata to an instance like that means that *every instance of that control will share the same collection*. There's an easy fix, just re-set it in the constructor:

```
SetValue(TasksProperty , new List<BarButtonItem>());
```

Now you can add to that collection as you would expect. In your `Loaded` event, enumerate the collection and add each item to the appropriate `Items` collection.

This has the benefit of reducing the amount of knowledge the parent control has of the user control, and allows for binding later.

When using it, you will need to wrap the collection in an `x:Array` tag so the framework knows its a collection:

```
<userControls:CollectionView.Tasks>
    <x:Array>
       ...
    </x:Array>
</userControls:CollectionView.Tasks>
```

Comment: Do I really have to use the `Loaded` event for this?

I did as you described, but not using the `Loaded` event, but the 5th button didn't appear, also there is no warning/error. Edited the question with the usage I tried.

Comment: @BrunoKlein Where did you do the enumeration? `Loaded` is the first place where the collection will actually be populated, so thats why I chose it.

Comment: 4 of the elements are populated in the XAML of the CollectionView, the other one is added on the usage of the CollectionView, as illustrated in my last edit. Isn't there a way to use XAML only?

Comment: @BrunoKlein And expose that property? No, not really. You are still using "just XAML", but you need to read in the data that was sent to you on the DP. That most convenient place to do that is in `Loaded`. Perhaps you could explain your concern with utilizing that event? This is still MVVM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69159/discussion-between-bruno-klein-and-bradleydotnet).